# What is a red airway on the VFR sectional?

Tags: usa, navigation, airspace

The VFR sectionals show a number of airways/routes marked in red. Here are several near KMTH, you can see B-646 extending east of the NDB:

[image: Bravo airways near KMTH]

There are others in Alaska that are lettered A, R or G, e.g. A-7 runs between the CMQ and MNL NDBs.

What are these airways or routes and how are they different from Victor airways?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These are *Red Federal Airways*, and can be found in [Order 7400.9](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/7400.9.pdf)

*Red* airways are one of a [1950s-ish system of airways](http://propspistonsandoldairliners.blogspot.com/2009/12/how-to-fly-airways-1950-style.html): Red, Blue, Green, Amber, which are designated by an NDB (rather than a VOR or VORTAC for a V or J route).

Green and Red airways go east/west, and Blue and Amber routes go north/south.

These routes were prioritized: GARB, with Green routes having the highest priority.

[image]