# What is the history of the name of airway?

Tags: airways

I am studying about airway. And I want to know about the history of designation of name of airway.
I have known that the first name of airway is colored airway(L/M frequency airway) like A586 or G13. 
But why we call them colors? I don't know the association of colors and airways. And how was the name of airway changed later?(like victor airway)
Please let me know in detail.

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/11737/62)

Comment: [Related](http://www.pprune.org/tech-log/132791-colored-airways.html), colored lights as beacons. I don't know if this is accurate. V is for VHF (VOR).